# Can't connect IntelliJ-IDEA to GitLab with SSH

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh, gitlab

I am trying to connect my GitLab repository with IntelliJ-IDEA, and it still cant connect to the repo. I have tried the next things:

- I have msysgit installed correctly
- Generated the SSH keys (https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)
- Added the key on GitLab keys
- Define the enviroment variables HOME USERPROFILE point to C:\Users\sebastian.garces.ssh. %USERPROFILE$/.ssh %HOME$/.ssh
- In IntelliJ changed SSH executable to Native

I did  a lot of things from this links:

- [How do I connect IntelliJ to GitHub using SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632511/how-do-i-connect-intellij-to-github-using-ssh)
- [How to store SSH host key in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746746/how-to-store-ssh-host-key-in-intellij-idea/26149790#26149790)

And many other google searchs

I dont know what else to do nothing is working.

**UPDATE:** When i try to Clone the repository and press the **Test** Button it loads and loads and nothing happen after a while it give me this error: *repository test has failed*

Comment: Post updated with more details of the error

Comment: webstorm should have native support

Comment: why do you even need plugins for this, can't you just add gitlab remate, ssh and push using webstorm?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try to install plugin:
`Settings` -> `Plugins` -> `Browse repositories` -> type `GitLab Projects Plugin`  minimum version 1.3.0

and go to `Settings` -> `Other Settings` -> `GitLab Settings`

Fill `GitLab Server Url` with `https://gitlab.com/` (ensure slash at the end) 
and

`GitLab API Key` with string (private token which is shown as the first thing on: https://gitlab.com/profile/account)

[image]

And then the test in IntelliJ IDEA will pass and you will be able to use ssh or https for each repository...

UPDATE: GitLab UI changed, so private tokens are created at https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens

Comment: sure, but I tried without the "http://" and it didn't work, as I assumed it adds it iself, but no.

Comment: Funny this works in intellij, but not in webstorm. Thanks for the concise guide

Comment: All of the above was still not enough for me. 'unable to access', 'ssl certificate problem' unable to get loca issuer certificate

Comment: check this https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html

Something must be missing in your C:\Users\User\.ssh folder (my looks like this http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2016/10/08/ssh.png)

Comment: What's the difference between the first (`git@gitlab.com...`) and the second (`https://gitlab.com...`) entry? From which one should I checkout?

Comment: first is ssh connection and the second is https connection, you can use any of them if your git host supports it, for GitHub chek this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041729/why-does-github-recommend-https-over-ssh

Answer (score 4):

The plugin worked for me after I found that a forward slash was missing after the .com in - GitLab Server Url with https://gitlab.com**/**
OS - Mac
IDE - IntelliJ
Plugin - GitLab Projects Plugin
HTH
SK

Answer (score 2):

If you are you Windows and tried to clone a gitlab project and it failed, make sure to :

1. Have setup a password in Gitlab (after registration, you'll need to create a password in your Account Setting)
2. In Windows, access the [Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager)
3. Find Suppress gitlab accesses
4. Retry cloning the project

For me, it worked!

Comment: Great advise, it helps! What I also did: put your Personal Access Token into password field. At https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens it clearly (but not visible enough) says: "You can also use personal access tokens to authenticate against Git over HTTP. They are the only accepted password when you have Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) enabled."

Answer (score 2):

For those struggling to get past the authentication issues when pulling from Gitlab. Of course, you can get it to work via the command line by adding the key to an ssh-agent. But IntelliJ didn't seem to hook on to that.

I got Git to work on IntelliJ by using the credential helper which will ask you and cache the credentials. Here is the config in question:
[image]