# Configure Gitlab account in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, gitlab

Can anyone explain how to configure a Gitlab account on PyCharm 3.4?

In the options I can see Github, but nothing about how to configure a Gitlab account.

Comment: Please refer to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975143/cant-connect-intellij-idea-to-gitlab-with-ssh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect IntelliJ-IDEA to GitLab with SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975143/cant-connect-intellij-idea-to-gitlab-with-ssh)

Answer (score 18):

Install gitlab Integration plugin from settings menu

Answer (score 4):

IN Pycharm Professional version 2018.2, (on a Mac) you'll have to go here:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7975-gitlab-projects and download the zip file.

Once downloaded, open Pycharm Pro, go to Pycharm > Preferences > PlugIns, then "install from disk". Simply navigate to the zipped file downloaded previously, click "Apply" and you will have the GitLab functionality enabled.

I would assume the Win/Lin procedures are very similar.