# pycharm gitlab plugin access error

Tags: pycharm, gitlab

I am trying to use gitlab in pycharm. When I want to clone the repository, it gives me this error:

```
IllegalAccessError: tried to access method 
com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.setOKActionEnabled(Z)V from class      
com.ppolivka.gitlabprojects.checkout.GitLabCheckoutDialog$2
```

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975143/cant-connect-intellij-idea-to-gitlab-with-ssh